# Windows 8.1 start screen slow to open folders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I use the windows 8.1 start screen to open specifically a folder, it takes almost 4 seconds to open up folder shortcuts. Its super annoying. If I open a program, its instant. If I open up the folder location of the *shortcut* that's displayed in the start screen, opening the folder shortcut is also instant.

Do other people have this issue? Does anyone know why the start screen might be so slow to open folders and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the folder contain large number of files? It could be that the Start Screen open the folder on particular view mode that's slow to initialize

Comment: It contains less than 20 files. What kind of view mode would be slow to initialize?

Comment: View mode with certain sorting sometimes take forever, but only on folder with thousand files. I can't replicate it here with Windows 8.1 x64. Do you have add ons on Explorer?

Comment: Well I have a Razor Blade (also x64) with their Synapse thing. I'm not sure if that's an explorer add on tho. I haven't installed anything like that myself.

Comment: Is it still slow if you restarted on safe mode?